# monitor a C++ OpenFrameworks application, for freezing or memory leaks, then force quit and restart?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, cron, freeze, openframeworks

I am running an Open Frameworks application. It sometimes freezes, and I'm not sure why and I want the application to force-quit then relaunch if it freezes. It doesn't crash, it just freezes.

Is there a way to monitor if there’s a memory leak , or if an application freezes or stops responding? Then ensure that the application force quits and restarts?

Of course figuring out why it's freezing is going to be best, but from the console I haven't yet been able to figure out when or why (it's after many hours of running)

Comment: What platform are you using?  There are different ways to find the problems on different platforms.  Depending on your situation, you can launch a program with the debugger and when it (finally) crashes, there should be some additional information for you.  Ideally (as you said) it would be best to figure out why the application is crashing in the first place.

Comment: Additionally, if it's not crashing altogether, you may need to add additional logging output (via `ofLog` or `std::cout` << xxx << `std::endl;`) to isolate the section of code that is causing the freezes.  Finally, if you are creating any objects using the `new` keyword, you might consider wrapping them in a smart pointer (like `ofPtr`) so their memory gets freed automatically OR carefully go through your code and make sure that every `new` is matched with an appropriate `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ofxWatchdog addon:
https://github.com/toolbits/ofxWatchdog

Launches a second app to watch yours for errors and stalls, then restarts.